# Retry mechanism for GraphStage akka

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

How can we retry/restart a graphStage in case of failures in postStop() ?

I am relatively new to akka and would really appreciate your help.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    source
    .via(Auditing)
    .via(someTransformations)
    .async.to(sink)
```

```
**Auditing** - a class extending GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[T,T], Future[Unit]]
    contains:
      - inport, outport, flowShape
      - overridden method createLogicAndMaterializedValue() -> returns (GraphStageLogic, Future[Unit])
          - overriden method postStop(){ 
                //contains audit logic
                // handles failures and throws exception
            }
          - setHandler for input and output.
```

Is it possible to add some retry mechanism for the class Auditing, so that it can reprocess the same data and ultimately land to sink without having to read same data from source again. Retry has to be attempted n times in m minutes.

I was thinking to utilize something like RetryFlow.withBackOff(), but seems like this is meant for Flow and not GraphStageLogic. Additionally, if I could just return the same data in failure scenario, this would work, but calling sethandler(outport) again from failure stage didn't actually go to sink again.

Note: I do have supervision decider to handle overall failures, but I am required to retry this GraphStage, rather than restarting/resuming the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether `RetryFlow.withBackOff()` does what you intend it to do, but: if your problem is that your `Auditing` is a `GraphStage` and `RetryFlow.withBackOff()` only takes a `Flow`, then you could just use `Flow.fromGraph`.

The following compiles just fine:

```
class Auditing[T] extends GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[T, T], Future[Unit]] {
  override def createLogicAndMaterializedValue(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): (GraphStageLogic, Future[Unit]) = ???
  override def shape: FlowShape[T, T] = ???
}

def retryingAuditingFlow[T]: Flow[T, T, Future[Unit]] = RetryFlow.withBackoff(
  minBackoff = ???,
  maxBackoff = ???,
  randomFactor = ???,
  maxRetries = ???,
  Flow.fromGraph(new Auditing[T]),
)(decideRetry = ???)

def source[T]: Source[T, _] = ???
def sink[T]: Sink[T, _] = ???

def theStream[T]: RunnableGraph[_] =
  source[T]
    .via(retryingAuditingFlow[T])
    .async.to(sink)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `RetryFlow` will not, in general retry elements that previously came into the flow.  Depending on one's use case, this may not be desirable.